# Trigonometric Equation from Hobson's Book

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve this equation:
$$
\cos(2x+y)=\sin(x-2y) \quad \text{and} \quad \cos(x+2y)=\sin(2x-y)
$$

Comment: By "solve this equation", do you mean "solve this *system*"? That is, do you seek $x$ and $y$ that satisfy *both* equations? ... This kind of ambiguity would be avoided if you included your own attempts to solve the problem. Telling what you know helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or guessing what you mean. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3420865/edit) to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use that $\sin(x-2y)=\cos\Bigl(x-2y-\tfrac\pi 2\Bigr)$, whence
$$2x+y\equiv \pm (x-2y-\tfrac\pi 2)\mod 2\pi,$$
and similarly for the other equation.

Comment: Thank you for the hint